# How to remove dots and extend boxplots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have some data that I'm trying to build some boxplots with, but I'm getting this error:

> Warning message: Removed 1631 rows containing non-finite values
>   (stat_boxplot).

There are no `NA` values and all the data seems fine.  How can I fix this as these are certainly valuable points in my data and should be extended by the whiskers?

**Data**

The data is fairly large, and I couldn't get a smaller subsample to produce the errors, so I'll just post the original data.

[dat.rds](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5mgogyclhim6hom/dat.rds?dl=0)

**ggplot2**

```
dat <- readRDS("./dat.rds")
ggplot(dat, aes(x = factor(year), y = dev)) + geom_boxplot() + ylim(-40, 260)
```

[image]

**Edit**

I was able to get it to work in `boxplot` with `range = 6'.  Is there a way to do this in ggplot?

```
boxplot(dev~year, data = d, range = 6)
```

[image]

Comment: See `coef` argument of `geom_boxplot`.

Comment: @Pascal That did it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `ylim` restriction and use the `coef` argument of `geom_boxplot`, then it works fine:

```
library(ggplot2)
download.file(url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/5mgogyclhim6hom/dat.rds?dl=1", tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".rds"))
dat <- readRDS(tf)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = factor(year), y = dev)) + 
  geom_boxplot(coef = 6)
```

[image]

Comment: It's still showing up for me.

Comment: @Amstell it works for me, it shouldn't show an error.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't show the error, but it's still showing the dots.  I don't understand why those are showing up when they should be included in the boxplot

Comment: If you don't want the outliers (i.e. dots) to show up, you can e.g. use `geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA)` (I'm using ggplot2 2.0.0 according to `packageVersion("ggplot2")`).

Comment: @Amstell  It is not clear what you want/don't want.

Comment: What if I want those outliers included?  I'm trying to show the shocks that are occuring the data and this is missing it

Comment: @Amstell If there are outliers (greater than 75% + 1.5xIQR and lower than 25% - 1.5xIQR), no.

Comment: @Pascal I've updated my question to include how I got it working in `boxplot`

Comment: @lukeA I updated your answer according to OP edit.