# Add geom_smooth to boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add a `geom_smooth()` trend to some a boxplot graph, but am not getting the layers correctly.

How can I merge these two together?

**geom_boxplot:**

```
ggplot(test) + geom_boxplot(aes(x=factor(year), y = dm))
```

[image]

**geom_smooth**

```
ggplot(test, aes(year, dm)) + geom_smooth()
```

[image]

**Both geom_boxplot and geom_smooth**

```
ggplot(test) + geom_boxplot(aes(x=factor(year), y = dm)) + geom_smooth(aes(x = year, y = dm))
```

[image]

Comment: By now you should know it is much easier to help if you provide a _minimal reproducible example_.

Comment: Hint: one layer uses year as a factor, and the other uses year as a continuous variable.

Comment: Hint 2: read the manual (`?geom_boxplot`). "You can also use boxplots with continuous x, as long as you supply a grouping variable."

Comment: Side note: I guess the data is [here in a previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602872/how-to-remove-dots-and-extend-boxplots-in-ggplot2/34602910#34602910).

Comment: Another closely related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911057/adding-a-simple-lm-trend-line-to-a-ggplot-boxplot)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I used the `mtcars` public data as it did not have the use by the asker.

```
data(mtcars)
```

Create the boxplot, as usual, and assign to object. I took a random variable as a factor for the boxplot and another variable as numeric.

```
g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(carb), mpg)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Add the geom_smooth. The geom_smooth inherits the necessary information from the geom_boxplot.

```
g + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=TRUE, aes(group=1))
```

Noted that the expression `aes(group=1)` it's required by the geom_smooth in this case. Without it, R returns the error:

*geom_smooth: Only one unique x value each group.Maybe you want aes(group = 1)?*

The values for fixing the line smoothing are the coefficients of the linear regression, whereas the intercept corresponds to the lowest level of the factor (carb = 1)

[image]

Comment: Can you add some explanation?