# geom_smooth lm line not drawn - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot the `lm` line using this code

```
df <- data.frame(c1=factor(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)),c2=c(65,42,56,75,43,43,21,23,12,12,21,11))
p <- ggplot(aes(x=c1,y=c2),data=df)
p + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

But the `lm` line is not shown. Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633714/adding-a-regression-line-on-a-ggplot

Comment: Why is 'c1' a `factor`?  Change it to `numeric` and you should be able to get the line

Comment: If you do happen to require a `factor`, set `aes(group = 1)`.

Comment: @Axeman: Thanks, that was it! Could you turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608767/add-geom-smooth-to-boxplot/34609280#34609280).

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `c1` is a `factor`.  Converting it to `numeric` will solve the problem

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  mutate(c1 = as.numeric(as.character(c1)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = c1, y = c2)) +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method="lm")
```